# Using angular directives for large views

Tags: angularjs

I have been on a few AngularJS projects now where directives are used extensively for handling views which end up with large amounts of JavaScript behind them. It doesn't feel quite right and they're also not the easiest thing to test unless you move the code out into controllers and bind that to the directive.

An example would be a large form created as a directive and a large link function placed on this. Not very testable, and its only used once in the whole application.

They do separate the code nicely in that you end up with code like this

```
<h1>example Header</h1>

<custom-form form-data="somemodel"></cutom-form>

<p>Lots of other stuff here</p>
```

Would be interested in how other people approach directives and views as I first thought directives should be really small components that are reused.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, only few occasions I will implement directive and these are also the rules I trying to stick with

1. common reusable components I can use anywhere in the project (e.g. a time input directive with an add-on dropdown menu allow to choose time units like second/minute/hour/day)
2. Extend or patch 3rd-party directive

Most of the time, should utilise AngularJS MVC structure to fully take its advantage.

Comment: If you have a screen made up of a few sections would you use controller + view then? Would that be using ngInclude?

Comment: For this case, yes using ngInclude would be a neat way to modularise your page view contents, but you might need to be careful that ngIncude fetch template asynchronously which you probably will encounter unexpected behaviours if you trying to manipulate ngIncluded DOM. We use ngInclude for header, footer, container and navigation menu in our index page, however we did encounter a problem using angular-loading-bar inside ngInclude see https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar/issues/217.

Comment: Interesting, I've not seen ngInclude used that much so far on projects that I've been on but it does sound like a neat way and on the plus side more testable that directive code, well more specifically large directive with lots of code behind